# Slony-I service filling up my event viewer in Windows

Tags: windows, database, postgresql, event-log, slony

I wrote a similar question before but I got no answers so I was thinking on asking again in a simpler way.

I have slony-I replicating databases in a windows environment (Master has windows xp and slave has windows 7, both with postgreSQL 8.2). I registered a service using slon -regservice in both master and slave and everything works fine.

The problem I have is that the service is writing logs in the event viewer every time it runs so I have 5 or 6 new logs every second. I was hoping that it would write only errors in the event viewer but it writes logs all the time and the event viewer in my master server is getting filled with them. Since windows xp has a limit of space in the event viewer, the logs make the event viewer reach its limit and all the applications that use the event viewer crash.

Is there a way to configure the slony service to avoid writing logs in the event viewer?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've been struggling with this problem for 2 weeks now and I read every tutorial in the web and all of them have the same instructions but none of them mentions the logs in the event viewer. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [postgreSQL slony-i windows service filling up my event viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240006/postgresql-slony-i-windows-service-filling-up-my-event-viewer)

Answer (score 1):

You probably ought to raise a bug in the [Slony-I](http://www.slony.info/) bug database or e-mail their mailing list. Since it is open source you could even re-build it and remove the unwanted event logging. Also, you don't need to register to receive event logs but you probably want errors.

You appear to be using Windows XP which is rather decrepit now – it's 10 years old! The modern versions of Windows have much more resilient event logs.

Finally, you could reconfigure the event log settings to try to avoid the problem. You could make the log much bigger (512KB default is quite small) and there appear to be other settings available.  Open the event viewer, right click one of the event logs and select properties.

Comment: The re-build idea sounds interesting. I'll give that a try. I am using windows XP... I know it's old but that's what my client has so I have to stick with it :(. For the moment I increased the size of the logs and configured the event log to replace older events no matter how old they are... I don't like this approach but it works for now. Thanks for the help!